# Disable dependency permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing the following problem at the moment:

I have developed app 'A' which uses permissions 1, 2, 3 and uses an 3rd party library 'B' as a dependency (added using maven & gradle).

Library 'B' uses the permissions 4 and 5. Now when building the app, the manifest merger adds the permissions 4 and 5 to app 'A'.

How can I prevent this and only have the permissions 1, 2 and 3 in the final manifest?

My first guess would be using one of the manifest merger markers as seen here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Markers

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use [Selector](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Selector)

> Each tools:node or tools:attr declaration can be augmented by a
>   tools:selector attribute which is contextual information on whether or
>   not the merging strategy should be applied to the current lower
>   priority XML description. For instance, this is useful when removing a
>   permission only if coming for one particular library as opposed to any
>   library:
>
> ```
> <permission
>       android:name="permissionOne"
>       tools:node="remove"
>       tools:selector="com.example.lib1">
> ```

It would be next according your initial requirements

```
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<uses-permission
    tools:node="removeAll"/>
```

but keep in mind that all other `<uses-permissions/>` will be removed.

Comment: How can I suppress the resulting warning when using your 2nd example? "name attribute should be defined"

Comment: @throwaway Use Android tools namespace `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`, add it into `<manifest/>`

Comment: Naw, I was talking about that, that the `<permission>` node requires an `andorid:name` attribute (according to lint), that's what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/V5YZp11.png the project still builds with that error but it's highly confusing

Comment: @throwaway, please check my update at answer, I played around test project to find it.

Comment: @gio .. hey.. I tried the same thing in my app but, my permission from the library still shows up. here in my question in Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417259/disable-dependency-library-permission

Answer (score 9):

As you know all libraries have a manifest file and will merge together.
you can remove a permission that is in one of your libraries by this:

```
tools:node="remove"
```

for an example removing location permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: easy step for me