# Disable Dependency Library permission

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my android project (using Android Studio), I have integrated a library which uses few extra permissions in its Manifest file. I want to remove one of the permissions which it uses for my app as i don't use that feature from the library and it is unwanted permission for my app.

I read about marker Selectors and tried it but it is not removing the permission.

This is what I added to my app manifest file:

```
<permission
        android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

But still while installing the app, I see the permission for "find accounts on the device" being asked.

can someone tell me what am I doing wrong or am I missing something?

My app manifest is kept in src/main location.

I tried other answers from StackOverflow but they did not solve the issue for me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable dependency permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997679/disable-dependency-permissions)

Comment: @Sushil please provide list of permissions from your apk, use command `aapt d permissions "app.apk"`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Changing word "permission" to "uses-permission" fixed the issue for me:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"
        tools:node="remove" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"
        tools:node="remove" />
```