# Android - Mystery Permissions Appear in Build Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Recently when uploading my app to Google Play, there was a warning that new permissions had been added:

[image: Google Play Permissions Warning]

I don't need these permissions. I found they may be coming from libraries that I'm using, so I removed all `<uses-permission>` from my `AndroidManifest.xml` to test this.

**1. Merged Manifest Report**

I checked the merged manifest report in `/app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt`, and it showed me the following permissions were being added by various libraries:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.INTERNET
uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
uses-permission#android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
uses-permission#com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
permission#com.pressbible.view.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
uses-permission#com.pressbible.view.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Those seem fine, but it doesn't explain where the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` come from.

**2. Final Manifest**

A whole slew of permissions appear at the bottom of the merged build manifest in `/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

I don't have these in my manifest, and they're not in the manifest report.

**3. Removal attempt**

Trying to add the lines

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.[permision-name]” tools:node=”remove” />
```

for each permission did not remove them.

**4. Merged Manifest View**

I also used the [Merged Manifest View](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) as suggested by Android docs and did not find any extra permissions other than reported in the `merger-debug-report.txt`

I tried searching manifest files from the other libraries but didn't find them.  I also tried invalidate and restarting, restarting my computer, and deleting all build files.  The mystery permissions still appear in the merged AndroidManifest.xml.

**How can I find where these permissions are coming from?**

**How can I remove them?**

Related questions:

[Disable Dependency Library permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417259/disable-dependency-library-permission)

[How to remove specific permission when build Android app with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616334/how-to-remove-specific-permission-when-build-android-app-with-gradle)

[Why does removing permission from AndroidManifest.xml not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774787/why-does-removing-permission-from-androidmanifest-xml-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer by accident while cleaning up some code - the permissions were added by a **plugin** rather than a library, which is why it wasn't showing up in the above reports.

We use an sdk for sharing called [ShareSDK](https://github.com/MobClub/ShareSDK-for-Android).  It gets added by this line in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.mob.sdk'
```

When I removed this line and the related code, the merged manifest no longer contained the extra permissions.  For any future users who stumble across this question, I would say beware of any libraries or plugins made for the Chinese market!