# Third party SDK MUwS violation in Google Play

Tags: android, permissions, sdk, google-play, policy-violation

A android third party application SDK which is in violation of tracking data like below

- MUwS-V: SDK collects a list of installed applications without consent
- Location-V: SDK collects location data without consent
- MUwS-V: SDK collects a large variety of hardware identifiers including build serial allowing for bridging PII with hardware IDs

How can I suppress / stop this tracking in the SDK and still use the SDK's main functionality? Anyway to control from main application which consumes the SDK?

Comment: Related: [Disable dependency permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27997679/295004) but if the SDK isn't following [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) I would be cautious about using such a SDK as you are still responsible for your [app's privacy policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?hl=en)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the reference, the permission is not related to manifest, its a well known SDK for their reputation, but am surprised they don't have any issues on their own app in google play or neither a ticket in github.

Comment: I would file an issue ticket. But realize that this question seems off-topic as it falls under: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/295004) since Google Play Store can change policy at any time and you don't control the code in the SDK.